# Updating stackblitz Angular version to the latest

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, stackblitz

I updated this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-demo-bnezpz?file=app/user-form/user-form.component.ts

to the latest angular version by pressing the refresh button in the dependencies tab.

The result is that it keeps asking me to install core-js, but it doesn't matter how many times I press install, it just keeps popping up and asking me to install core-js. What's wrong here?

Comment: Looks like 2.6.9 was the last of the core-js' 2.x versions. Today Angular 8.1.1 was released and still no update to core-js 3.x. Here is the issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13954

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There seems to be some incompatibility in package version. Uninstall the  `core-js:3.0.0.` is not working. You can update the version manually by installing `core-js@2.5.4`.

### Edit:

Tried installing `core-js@3.0.0` in local, It seems like there are some breaking changes in the latest `core-js` package. Previously (`version < 3.0.0`), the `javascript` specific things were in sub-folders in core-js (like `core-js/es6/symbol, core-js/es7/reflect`).

From `version 3.0.0`, all these things have been moved to `core-js/es/*`. Various angular packages depend on the previous versions and are not able to find the directories at right place, thus you are getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2021-08-16, `@3.x` still ask you to **Install** even ng is upgraded to `12x`. So, simply

1. delete `core-js` from Dependency
2. enter `core-js@2.6.9`, hit <enter>